# Image from resources as a footer in excel

Tags: c#, image, excel, footer

How can I use an image from resources as a footer in created excel file?

this definately will not work:

```
xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooterPicture = Properties.Resources.stopka;
```

since:
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Graphic'

Ok this works:

```
  xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooterPicture.Filename = Application.StartupPath + "\\stopka.png";
  xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooterPicture.LockAspectRatio = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
  xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooterPicture.Width = 590;
  xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "&G";
```

But it is not what I needed. I would like to get the image from project resources not from application folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly CurrAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFrom(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath);
  System.IO.Stream stream = CurrAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream("Oferty_BMGRP.Resources.stopka.png");
  string temp = Path.GetTempFileName();
  System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(stream).Save(temp);


  xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooterPicture.Filename = temp; //Application.StartupPath + "\\Resources\\stopka.png";
  xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooterPicture.LockAspectRatio = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoTriState.msoTrue;
  xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooterPicture.Width = 590;
  xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooter = "&G";
```

the image "stopka.png" had to be set as embeded resource.

Answer (score 0):

Since microsoft doesn't provide the set option for CenterFooterPicture property

The following is the documentation available in MSDN

CenterFooterPicture  -  Returns a Graphic object that represents the picture for the center section of the footer. Used to set attributes about the picture.

[Link to Refer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms280798%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Comment: Sure, as shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195659.aspx I us eit to set properties, and put it to the file with ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "&G". But still it only allows me to use a file from outside with specific path. I hoped that I will be able to use resource file.

Comment: In that VBA they set the Image source first, then set ActiveSheet.PageSetup.LeftFooter = "&G". Are you doing the same ?

Comment: Yes. There is no problem with setting an image from file saved on the disc. But I would like to use embedded resource - image. Example I used worked easly, but I cannot use resource file there - at least I do not know how.

Comment: whether you mean to say loading from disc working ? Am i right ?

Comment: Could you please update the full set of code if it's works from disc ?

Comment: Yes. the code shown in the link (and with some modifications works), but that is not what I was looking fore, since I still need to have file on the disc. I will stay at this solution if it will not be possible to get the file path of resource image.

Comment: That links shows for VBA Script but your requirement in c#? Am i right ?

Comment: No. I changed VBA to C# and the 4 lines code shown up there works. But I look for alternate solution similar to the `xlWorkSheet.PageSetup.CenterFooterPicture = Properties.Resources.stopka;`. But there is problem since `centerfooterpicture.filename` can not get image from resources